# I can't use my password

Tags: password

I've just installed ubuntu 14 and setted my password
but when i'm trying to install other software and ubuntu ask me to enter my password, it's always wrong even though i'm sure it's the right password. that's also happen when i logout and try to login again

Comment: Just out of curiosity, your password doesn't happen to be [Enter], does it? The reason I ask is because it's possible to set the desktop to log in automatically. This doesn't mean the account doesn't have a password. Whatever password you entered during setup is the password needed for `sudo`. Also, maybe you accidentally had caps lock on/num lock off? If you can answer this I have an answer ;)

Comment: No, my password doesn't have an enter key.
and i'm sure caps weren't on.

btw i've tried some sudo commands but still the same, password is incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright then. Sounds like you need to reset your password. Follow these steps and you'll be on your way!

1. Reboot
2. At boot menu, select "Ubuntu (recovery mode)"
3. At the next menu, select "Root" using the up/down keys and hit enter.
4. Run this command to mount the root filesystem as read/write (it starts off in read-only): `mount -o remount,rw /`
5. Finally: `passwd [username]` (where [username] is the username of your account).
6. `reboot`

Comment: do you have an idea how this problem is caused?

Comment: Also what would be the new password if i run this commands?

Comment: 1. No idea other than a caps lock/num lock error. 2. It asks you what you want to set the password to.